# Проверить на возможность решения судоку

Tags: алгоритм

написал решатель для судоку который работает по принципу брутфорса, само собой такой решатель может думать вечно в случае если судоку решить невозможно, есть ли какие-нибудь алгоритмы для проверки возможности решения судоку?

Comment: Просто решить :) Это не просто просто, а очень просто, если немного подумать, а не брутфорсом. Немного труднее проверить - однозначно ли решение судоку. Если уж [премьер Сингапура сумел](https://www.facebook.com/leehsienloong/photos/a.344710778924968.83425.125845680811480/905828379479869/)...

Comment: У меня задача написать решатель а не решать самому. К слову решатель отлично работает.

Comment: Ну а я о чем? Тот решатель пишется за полчаса... Напишите **нормальный** решатель, а не майтесь проверками, есть ли решение. Если ваш решатель **отлично** работает - то зачем вам проверятель существования решения? Решатель решение не дает - значит, его нет.

Comment: Всмысле? У меня есть функция которая решает судоку из заданого поля, а если решения нет то она думает слишком долго прежде чем уведомить об этом.

Comment: Блин, ну напишите нормальную программу, которая будет решать за реальное время - моя неоптимизированная решалка, например, где-то за 0.2с отрабатывает. Это не слишком долго? Это же очень простая задача. Понятно, что перебором можно любую задачу сделать слишком сложной, но зачем?

Comment: Если не секрет какой она алгоритм использует?

Comment: Сначала - пока есть однозначно определяемые клетки, просто заполняет их. Дальше, когда и если они заканчиваются - начинает ветвления с отсечением + проверки на однозначное решение (хотя можно на этом уровне оптимизировать - еще несколько вариантов просмотреть - те же цепочки из трех клеток с тремя возможными значениями и т.п. - посмотрите, в Интернете есть сайты с алгоритмами решения судоку). Но даже такая отрабатывает за где-то 0.2 секунды сложные варианты; простоые - ну, десятки миллисекунд.

Comment: 0.2 - это когда-то попалась статья, где утверждалось, что самый сложный однозначно разрешимый судоку - 800000000003600000070090200050007000000045700000100030001000068008500010090000400 - это для него.

Comment: В [документации](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) sqlite есть пример решателя судоку на sql (может кому интересно покажется). Пример в конце.

Comment: @Harry, так ведь никто не гарантирует, что решение однозначное. Можно вообще пустое поле отправить на решение.

Comment: @Harry, попробуй скормить своему решателю вот такое поле: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy1EI.png

Comment: Написал (само собой), что решения нет.

Comment: @Harry, насколько быстро? А если 2 заменить на 1?

Comment: @Qwertiy Значит, так - я дописал, чтоб только время счета фиксировать. Та самая сложная, что я говорил - примерно 163 ms, неразрешимая - сообщает об отсутствии решений через 43 ms, если заменить 2 на 1 - через 0,25 ms дает возможное решение.

Comment: @Harry, как-то быстро. Там же всё равно перебор должен быть? Потому что гарантированных цифр там ни одной нет.

Comment: Ну, я это делал давно, точные детали не помню. Вот тут [код](https://github.com/disputant/Sudoku/), работает - и ладно... :)